# Notice- undefined variable post and trying to get property of non-object

Tags: custom-post-type-archives, notices

i created a custom post type interview for that i also created custom post taxonomy interview_category and that custom taxonomy have some terms like students, teachers and some more. i trying to get the name of terms inside archive-interview.php but it show notice like undefined variable post and trying to get property of non-object.
my code inside archive-interview is:

```
<?php if(have_posts()): 
        // $tax = $wp_query->get_queried_object();?>
        <section class="interview_main_wrapper">
            <div class="interview_head  dropdown">
                <button class="black-btn" type="button">
                  <a id="dropdownMenu1" class="auto_drop" data-toggle="dropdown">
                  <?php   // Get terms for post
                   $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'dastak_interview_category' );
                   // Loop over each item since it's an array
                   if ( $terms != null ){
                   foreach( $terms as $term ) {
                   // Print the name method from $term which is an OBJECT
                   print $term->slug ;
                   // Get rid of the other data stored in the object, since it's not needed
                   unset($term);
                  } }else{
                     echo 'All Interview';  

                  } ?></a>
```

i get name but notice shows every time.

Comment: the `$post` object is not set unless you call `the_post()` function.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a custom loop. Please use $query->post to get the post object.

Comment: May you please elaborate your answer?